# Flutter: Password Check

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I will enter the password to the user 2 times. but i don't know how to check this. How can I be sure that both passwords are spelled the same? can i do this?

here is my code,(I just put the relevant parts in order not to be long)

```
class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              
              _paddingPasswordWidget('Password', 'Password'),
              _paddingPasswordWidget('Password Again', 'Password Again'),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


    _paddingPasswordWidget(String hintTextStr, String labelTextStr) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 22, right: 22),
    child: TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: HexColor('#868686'),
      ),
      decoration: CommonInputStyle.textFieldStyle(
        hintTextStr: hintTextStr,
        labelTextStr: labelTextStr,
      ),
      obscureText: true,
    ),
  );
}


class CommonInputStyle {
  static InputDecoration textFieldStyle(
      {String labelTextStr = "", String hintTextStr = ""}) {
  return InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 20),
      labelText: labelTextStr,
      hintText: hintTextStr,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: HexColor('#868686')),
      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: HexColor('#868686')),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: HexColor('#EEF2F4'),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting textEditingController in your fields, then you compare them. Something like this:

```
var textFieldPasswordController = TextEditingController();
var textFieldConfirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
```

then you pass these as controllers in your TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
controller: textFieldPasswordController //as an example
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: HexColor('#868686'),
      ),
```

Now you just need to check if textFieldPasswordController.text equals to textFieldConfirmPasswordController.text. You can check this in the onChange or validator function of TextFormField

```
if(textFieldPasswordController.text == textFieldConfirmPasswordController.text){
   print("Access granted");
} else{
   print("Try again");
}
```